# Filtering numbers starting with a given digit (regex)

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to implement a regex that allows to filter out a set of numbers that start with a given number. For example, let's say that we have the following set of numbers:

- 5700
- 57
- 1.1
- 0.3
- 0
- 5
- 10

If I type "0" on my input, the result should give me the subset:

- 0
- 0.3

Similarly, if I type "57", the results should give me the subset:

- 57
- 5700

If I type "0." on my input, the result should be "0.3". I tried to implement this with two different regex, with no good results:

- /^digit/gm
- /^digit.*/gm

Being "digit" the variable that contains the value of the input. If I type "0" on my input, I just get "0.3" as a result, instead of "0" and "0.3". Please any suggestion regarding the proper implementation of this regex will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Just turn everything into a string and use [.startsWith](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/startsWith)

Comment: Also, please add a [mre] to your question because it also depends on how you're building the regex from the variable.

Comment: Your regex seems correct, and it should match the input as you described it. But if you're just matching the first part of the string literally, then regex is a bit overkill - something like `foo.substring(0, input.length) === input` should work.

Comment: If the entry is held by the variable `s` (e.g., `'0'`, `'0\.1'`, '`34\.1`) then it would appear you want to attempt to match the string against the regex `/^#{s}\d*/`. If, for example, the string were `"0.123"` and the pattern were `s = "0\.1"`, then the string would match `/^#{s}\d*/ #=> /^0\.1\d*/`.

Comment: It works for me: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/ahjsvzck/

Comment: @Chris, that does not ensure all characters are digits and possibly a period.

Comment: @CarySwoveland No, but the input is always a set of numbers, so there's no need to check for that as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
const arr = [5700,
  57,
  1.1,
  0.3,
  0,
  5,
  10
]
const input = 57;
const res = arr.filter(x => x.toString().startsWith(input));
console.log(res)
```